# Verification of platform-signed system apps

Tags: android, apk, android-source, signature

Android apps signed with the platform key of a certain build can obtain system privileges [according to this documentation.](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/sign_builds#certificates-keys)
I am wondering, how and where these apks are verified. There has to be some kind of **reference**, either another platform-signed apk or a copy of the public key. I have two assumptions:

- the certificate of `/system/framework/framework-res.apk`
- the certificate stored in `/system/etc/security/otacerts.zip`

Both are self-signed certificates containing the public key. In my case I can see that they are different (serial no).

The reason for this is that I want to add an app with system privileges to a ROM and I am trying to find out where I have to resign apks or exchange certificates.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the source code of the device your focused on, it's easy to resign an apk with a platform signature.

So I guess you do not have the source code, and somehow you got the root access, then you want to push a apk on /system and make it privileged by resign it to the platform signature, right?

If my guess is right, it's impossible to do this. signing an apk needs a private key, which only exist on a signature server, your can't get it.

I'll try to answer the very first question. Correct me if I'm wrong. Though I'm not 100% sure, I prefer the signature check is doing by comparing the framework-res.apk's signature with the target one. I guess the /system/etc/security/otacerts.zip is used for doing the dm-verify when ota updating.